# Trigger multiple test using MOCHA

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

Context:

My test folder `automationSuite\apiTestSuite` has around 4 test files
`userAPIValidation.js orderAPIValidation.js verifyAPIEndPoints.js verifyHealthEndPoints.js`

And also I am using the mocha multi reporter to generate the Jnuit report file. As follows, from the snippet from `package.json` file

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha automationSuite\\apiTestSuite\\verifyAPIEndPoints.js --reporter mocha-junit-reporter --reporter-options mochaFile=./autoTestResult/test-results.xml"
  },
```

And I want to add `userAPIValidation.js & orderAPIValidation.js`  and generate the separate report for each

like `mocha automationSuite\\apiTestSuite\\userAPIValidation.js &  mocha automationSuite\\apiTestSuite\\orderAPIValidation.js` (note this is just example to show my intention)

is there any way I can do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do it,

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha automationSuite\\apiTestSuite\\verifyAPIEndPoints.js --reporter mocha-junit-reporter --reporter-options mochaFile=./autoTestResult/test-results.xml",
    "test:userAPI" : "mocha automationSuite\\apiTestSuite\\userAPIValidation.js --reporter mocha-junit-reporter --reporter-options mochaFile=./autoTestResult/userAPI-test-results.xml",
    "test:orderAPI" : "mocha automationSuite\\apiTestSuite\\orderAPIValidation.js --reporter mocha-junit-reporter --reporter-options mochaFile=./autoTestResult/orderAPI-test-results.xml",
    "test:all": "npm run test & npm run test:userAPI & npm run test:orderAPI"
  },
```

For execution we can just use :

`npm run test:all` for executing all test

`npm run test:orderAPI` for executing any specific test